# How to get bits from a SecKeyRef

Tags: macos, cocoa, public-key, seckeyref

My aim is to compare two public keys.
How can I get NSData from a SecKeyRef.
Is there a direct way to compare SecKeyRef instances?
P.S. - I dont have the private key with me.

Edit :Its for mac not iOS.

Comment: The question states "It's for mac not iOS", but your comment states "It's for iOS not Mac", so which is it?

Comment: actually someone posted a comment giving a link answering my question. But the solution was for iOs.He deleted it I think.
I'll delete it .Its misleading

Comment: To retrieve the NSData, using the keychain services, I expect you need to call SecItemExport: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Security/Reference/keychainservices/index.html

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 ways to do it

1. Use `SecKeyCopyAttributes` function

   ```
   CFDictionaryRef attrs = SecKeyCopyAttributes(key);
   CFDataRef data = (CFDataRef) CFDictionaryGetValue(attrs, kSecValueData);
   CFShow(data);
   ```
2. Use `SecKeyCopyExternalRepresentation` function

   ```
   CFDataRef data = SecKeyCopyExternalRepresentation(key, NULL);
   CFShow(data);
   ```

**Output**

```
<CFData 0x102067100 [0x7fff8df69980]>{length = 294, capacity = 1024, bytes = 0x30820122300d06092a864886f70d0101 ... 835b510203010001}
```